# How can I launch socket-io on a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, socket.io

I want to make it so when I click an element with class chatroom, socketio will connect to flask. 
Here is the server side:

```
@socketio.on('joined')
def handle_connections(data):
    username = session['Username']
    socketio.emit('status', {'msg': username + ' has entered the room.' });
```

Here is the javascript

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port );
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chatRoom').click(function(event){   
            event.preventDefault();

            socket.on( 'connect', function() {
                socket.emit( 'joined', {});
            }); 
    });

    socket.on( 'status', function(data){
            console.log("user connected");
    });
});
```

Without the jquery selector, the chatroom works. How can I make it work with the selector?

Comment: Is it possible the socket is emitting the 'connect' event before the listener is created?  Try moving your declaration of var socket inside the jquery event.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can send ajax call request for connect and handle that in socket.
In think below code snippet can help you other way round.

```
`$(document).on('click', function(event){
    socket.emit('myClick', {id: event.target}); 
 }
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost'); 
    socket.on('myClick', function (data) { 
    $(data.id).trigger('click'); 
 }
```